# Dynamic json building: JObject vs Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, json.net

Say I need to build a json string from  pairs (e.g., coming from a database where the column name is the key).

Is it better/faster to:

a) create a `JObject` and add the `<string, JToken>` pairs (getting the tokens with the `JToken.FromObject`) ; at the end call the `JObject.ToString()` method
(here is it better to use the Add method or the indexer set?)

b) create a `Dictionary` and add the `<string, object>` pairs; at the end call the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` passing the dictionary

c) Any other way?

I'm worried about performance since this will be used multiple times per second.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've personally used the code found on that answer many times to answer questions just like this.  Give it a go, and if you have problems, [edit] to add details for your benchmarks and @me to reopen.

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/